# What is the error in this :ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT CU.CUST_CODE
FROM AR_CUSTOMERS CU
WHERE CU.CUST_CODE=TM.CUST_CODE
UNION
SELECT ITS.ITEMS_CODE
FROM AR_ITEMS ITS
WHERE ITS.ITEMS_CODE = TD.ITEM_CODE
UNION
SELECT ITS.ITEMS_NAME
FROM AR_ITEMS ITS
WHERE TM.INVOICE_NO = TD.INVOICE_NO AND ITS.ITEMS_CODE = TD.ITEM_CODE
UNION
SELECT TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MON-YY')MON, TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MM-YY')MM
FROM AR_TRANS_MASTER TM
SELECT SUM(TD.QUANTITY)QUANTITY, SUM(TD.PRICE)UNIT
FROM AR_TRANS_DETAIL TD
WHERE ITS.ITEMS_CODE = TD.ITEM_CODE
TM.JOB_DATE  :STARTDATE AND :STOPDATE
GROUP BY 
CU.CUST_CODE,ITS.ITEMS_CODE,ITS.ITEMS_NAME,TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MM-YY')
ORDER BY
MM ASC
```

Let me know what is the error is this, can anyone explain or rectify

> 933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
>        *Cause:
>        *Action:
>        Error at Line: 15 Column: 1

AFTER THIS CORRECTION OF (union) MADE , now existing a error :

ORA-00904: "TM"."CUST_CODE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 22

how to find this

Comment: As the error message implies, there's a missing semicolon after `FROM AR_TRANS_MASTER TM` in line 14

Comment: You cant unnion queries with different number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, Line 15 missing `UNION`.

```
SELECT CU.CUST_CODE
FROM AR_CUSTOMERS CU
WHERE CU.CUST_CODE=TM.CUST_CODE
UNION
SELECT ITS.ITEMS_CODE
FROM AR_ITEMS ITS
WHERE ITS.ITEMS_CODE = TD.ITEM_CODE
UNION
SELECT ITS.ITEMS_NAME
FROM AR_ITEMS ITS
WHERE TM.INVOICE_NO = TD.INVOICE_NO AND ITS.ITEMS_CODE = TD.ITEM_CODE
UNION
SELECT TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MON-YY')MON, TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MM-YY')MM
FROM AR_TRANS_MASTER TM
UNION
SELECT SUM(TD.QUANTITY)QUANTITY, SUM(TD.PRICE)UNIT
FROM AR_TRANS_DETAIL TD
WHERE ITS.ITEMS_CODE = TD.ITEM_CODE
TM.JOB_DATE  :STARTDATE AND :STOPDATE
GROUP BY 
CU.CUST_CODE,ITS.ITEMS_CODE,ITS.ITEMS_NAME,TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MON-   YY'),TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MM-YY')
ORDER BY
MM ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing a 'UNION' (or any other intended operator) between these lines:

```
FROM AR_TRANS_MASTER TM
SELECT SUM(TD.QUANTITY)QUANTITY, SUM(TD.PRICE)UNIT
```

You probably intended:

```
SELECT CU.CUST_CODE
FROM AR_CUSTOMERS CU
WHERE CU.CUST_CODE=TM.CUST_CODE
UNION
SELECT ITS.ITEMS_CODE
FROM AR_ITEMS ITS
WHERE ITS.ITEMS_CODE = TD.ITEM_CODE
UNION
SELECT ITS.ITEMS_NAME
FROM AR_ITEMS ITS
WHERE TM.INVOICE_NO = TD.INVOICE_NO AND ITS.ITEMS_CODE = TD.ITEM_CODE
UNION
SELECT TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MON-YY')MON, TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MM-YY')MM
FROM AR_TRANS_MASTER TM
UNION
SELECT SUM(TD.QUANTITY)QUANTITY, SUM(TD.PRICE)UNIT
FROM AR_TRANS_DETAIL TD
WHERE ITS.ITEMS_CODE = TD.ITEM_CODE
TM.JOB_DATE  :STARTDATE AND :STOPDATE
GROUP BY 
CU.CUST_CODE,ITS.ITEMS_CODE,ITS.ITEMS_NAME,TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MON-YY'),TO_CHAR(TM.JOB_DATE,'MM-YY')
ORDER BY
MM ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you in case of union you cant use the reference name in one query to the other.
Example

```
  select a.col1 from tab1 a where a.col1=b.col2
  union
  select b.col2 from tab2 b;
```

b is the reference of a table in query 2 ,i think it cant be used in query 1. Please do check